# RegionPlot3D incorrectly plots regions defined by memoized functions

Tags: plotting, regions, memoization

RegionPlot3D incorrectly plots regions defined by memoized functions.

A memoizer:

```
ClearAll[Memoize];
SetAttributes[Memoize, HoldFirst];

Memoize[func_, cache_ : <||>] :=
 Module[
  {c = cache}
  , If[KeyExistsQ[c, #], c[#], c[#] = func] &
 ]
```

A function and its memoization:

```
ClearAll[G, GM];

G = Function[
     {x, y, z}
     , Sin[x + y + z] + Max[Sin[x] + Sin[y] + Sin[z]]
    ];

GM = Memoize[G[#1, #2, #3]];
```

Sanity check:

```
In[1]:= Table[Table[RandomReal[], 3]*2 \[Pi], 9999];
In[2]:= Plus @@ Abs[G @@@ % - GM @@@ %]
Out[2]= 0.
```

Plot of G, a function which is not memoized:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 
 -0.4 <= G[x, y, z] <= 0.4
 
 , {x, 0, 8 \[Pi]}
 , {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}
 , {z, 0, 4 \[Pi]}
 
 , PlotPoints -> 100
 , MaxRecursion -> 1
 , Boxed -> False
 , Axes -> False
 , Mesh -> None
 , PlotRange -> All
 , BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}
 
 ]
```

[image: Good plot]

Plot of GM, the same function, but memoized:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 
 -0.4 <= GM[x, y, z] <= 0.4
 
 , {x, 0, 8 \[Pi]}
 , {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}
 , {z, 0, 4 \[Pi]}
 
 , PlotPoints -> 100
 , MaxRecursion -> 1
 , Boxed -> False
 , Axes -> False
 , Mesh -> None
 , PlotRange -> All
 , BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}
 
 ]
```

[image]

What is going on, and is there a way to correctly plot a function that has been memoized?

Comment: this is probably version/os related. I get the same picture from `G` and `GM` in version 11.3.0 (windows 10-64bit).

Comment: You are making memoization much too complicated.  Here is an example how to do it: f[x_,y_,z_ :=f[x,y,z]] = definition

Comment: try using `Evaluate[-0.4 <= GM[x, y, z] <= 0.4]`?

Comment: @DanielHuber It is useful to be able to memoize anonymous functions. As you can imagine, the example provided in the post has been modified/simplified from the actual use case.

Comment: Perhaps you should be aware that if you try to memoize the result of something like `f[1.]`, you won't be able to use the effort taken for that in computing e.g. `f[Total[ConstantArray[0.1, 10]]]` (i.e. memoization does not interact well with floating-point computations).